# Highest Quality Possible in SimpleScreenRecorder

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xfce, recording

I have installed [SimpleScreenRecorder](https://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/) On My Linux Machine but I recorded and Edited Some Videos With it Like This [Example](https://youtu.be/p970tQJnoME) But the Recorded Quality is Not Good Enough, Please Tell me Some Settings Which I Can use For Recording Quality

My PC Details:
2 GB Ram, 2.2GHz Intel Dual Core Processor & 500GB HDD & Linux Mint XFCE4

Comment: The video link is no longer available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hardly a question for unix stackexchange, but here's what I'm using to get good results off this application:

[image]

The key is specifying a low enough constant rate factor. 6 is close to lossless and you can specify 0 for lossless encoding but the resulting file might be huge.

Answer (score 0):

It depends mostly on the system because when you have a slow machine you get better results when you get up with the speed and leave the constant rate factor on 23 because 23 is actually a near lossless default. In my case to stream a  full hd movie I get the best results with speed on medium and rate factor on 23 by a setting of 30 frames per second what is enough for hd movies, and I get a file size of about 2 GB. When i stream and record older series for example i scale on 720p 30 frames per second mp4 h264 codec with speed on slow and 28 rate factor what is near lossless to older series and movies the result is median-good quality by a filesize of about 300 MB 60 minutes